# Production mode not enabled in Jhipster Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I am using Jhipster to develop a Spring application.

When I need to deploy, I use `mvn -Pprod package`. This command generates 2 War files: `xxx.war` and `xxx.original.war`. I deploy the `xxx.original` War file in a local Tomcat.

Although I am convinced this is the right procedure, the application is still behaving as when the DEV profile is used.

Is the production mode supported or not ?

Answer (score 7):

Production mode *is* supported by Jhipster, it is the procedure detailed above which is simply not complete.

**Reason**

The `-Pprod` argument is used to profile the build for production mode, but it does not tell Tomcat to actually enable that mode so it falls back to the default `dev' mode.

**Solution**

As explained [in Jhipster on-line documentation](http://jhipster.github.io/production.html), to enable production mode, simply add `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` to your `JAVA_OPTS`. You may achieve this by editing your `<tomcat-home>/bin/setenv.sh / .bat` file, for instance.

Comment: how can you check the prod mode is activated?

Comment: Remember first, that the `spring.profiles.active` property is accessible throughout your application as a system one. Then simply use it to conditionally load a `css`. This style sheet may set a specific header background color or display a colorful ribbon (position top-left of page, red background, white text, golden top and bottom borders, 45 deg rotation).

Comment: According to jhipster docs: `Please note that this WAR file uses the profile we selected when building it. As it was built using the prod file in the previous section, it will therefore run with the prod profile.`  And also: `When you run your production application from a WAR file, the default is to use the same profile(s) as used during packaging. If you want to override this, you can explicitly provide an alternative in VM argument: ./java -jar jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --spring.profiles.active=...` So it should have been run with the prod profile and not the dev profile.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following in conf/catalina.properties

spring.profiles.active=prod

for tomcat to have the prod profile picked.

if no profile is provided - JHipster picks the default profile - which is dev.

You can take a look at ApplicationWebXml.java, Application.java to see that, dev profile is made default.

One more change we have done to avoid any issues is

1. Set prod as default profile in master
2. Keep dev as default profile in develop branch (where active development happens)

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to package:

```
./mvnw -Pprod -Dspring.profiles.active=prod package
```